# PHP looping in table

Tags: php

I'm trying create loop in my table, there is 4 item, when column is 3 then create new row . The current output is like this:

```
x
x
x
x
```

Here's my code:

```
<table border="0">
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($list_items as $item){ // there is 4 item
        $i++;
        echo "<tr>";
        if ($i <= 3) { ?>
            <td class="text-center"  style="width:83.14px; height:60.47px; font-size:0.6em">
              <?php echo $item['productId'] ?>
              <br>
              <br>
              <?php echo $item['qty'] ?>
            </td>
        <?php }
      }
      echo "</tr>";
      ?>
  </table>
```

What i expected is like this:

```
x|x|x
x
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to move your `tr` inside of the loop.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `flex` layout instead of a `table` layout. There that line break would be mere CSS rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
<?php

foreach (array_chunk($list_items,3) as $items) {
    echo '<tr>';        

    foreach($items as $item){
?>
        <td class="text-center"  style="width:83.14px; height:60.47px; font-size:0.6em">
          <?php echo $item['productId'] ?>
          <br>
          <br>
          <?php echo $item['qty'] ?>
        </td>
<?php
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the comment section of your question, Sirko is right.

Anyway you can do this like below;

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($list_items as $item) {
        if($i % 3 == 0)
            echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td> bla bla bla </td>';

        if($i % 3 == 0)
            echo '</tr>';

        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to below, it should work.

```
    <table border="0">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($list_items as $item){ // there is 4 item
            $i++;
            echo "<tr>";
            if($i%3==0) echo echo "</tr><tr>";
            ?>
                <td class="text-center"  style="width:83.14px; height:60.47px; font-size:0.6em">
                  <?php echo $item['productId'] ?>
                </td>
<td>
                  <?php echo $item['qty'] ?>
                </td>
            <?php
          }
          if($i%3!=0)
          echo "</tr>";
          ?>
      </table>
```

Comment: Some explanation on what you changed and why?

Comment: see the if condition, it will print close tr and start new tr if items is reached to 3.

Answer (score 0):

try this ==>

```
    <table border="0">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($list_items as $item) { // there is 4 item
            if ($i % 3 == 0)  // for i=0,3,6,9 <tr> tag will open
                echo "<tr>";

            ?>
            <td class="text-center"  style="width:83.14px; height:60.47px; font-size:0.6em">
                <?php echo $item['productId'] ?>
                <br>
                <br>
                <?php echo $item['qty'] ?>
            </td>
            <?php
            if ($i % 3 == 0)  // for i=0,3,6,9 <tr> tag will close
                echo "</tr>";

$i++;
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```